# Why can't I use combineByKey in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I write this code in Spark 2.4.5 :

```
df_join is a dataframe.    

var comByKeyResult: Dataset[((String, String), (Double, Int))] = df_join
      .map(x => ((x(1).toString, x(3).toString), (x(9).toString.toDouble, x(1).toString.toInt)))
```

When I try to write `comByKeyResult.combineByKey,` the method combineByKey is not available. Why ?

I import the following libraries : import org.apache.spark.rdd._. Should I have to add other librariries or packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combineByKey` is a transformation operation on PairRDD

You need to convert your dataframe/dataset to `rdd` then map it to a `pairRdd`
In your case , just a small change:

```
val yourPairRdd = df_join
.rdd
.map(x => ((x(1).toString, x(3).toString), (x(9).toString.toDouble, x(1).toString.toInt)))

//yourPairRdd.combineByKey
```